# Objects from different contexts even though they're not

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I'm getting the error...

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
reason: 'Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'part' between objects in different contexts
```

I've tracked the context for the fetch of the `Part` object and the `Selection` object and they are 100% coming from the same context.

I then use a dictionary...

```
@{
    @"part" : thePart,
    @"name" : @"Some name",
    @"value" : @"Some value"
}
```

And the function...

```
Selection *selection = [Selection insertInManagedObjectContext:self.innerContext];
[selection setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:dictionary];
```

`self.innerContext` is the same context as the one I used to fetch the Part object. It's even owned by the same object.

I'm not sure what I can do to check beyond this as everything should be working?

**EDIT**

OK, not really sure what's going on here.

When I get to saving the selection the `part.managedObjectContext` is `nil`...

???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that `Selection` and `Part` are `NSManagedObject`s.

If so, I would start by checking the `managedObjectContext` property on `thePart` and `selection` just as a sanity check.  If they're equal, then I'd be a little baffled.  If they're different, then I'd recheck the way in which those objects are fetched/created.

If either `managedObjectContext` is nil, that's a sign that one of the objects has been deleted from its managed object context.

Comment: Yeah, I was following the wrong object which is why I was getting confused. Putting it right now hopefully.